# return multiple values from dropdown in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, button

I have this custom dropDown button and I want to get two values when I select one value from the list.

Here is the custom dropdown button

```
Widget customJsonDropDown(List? jsonList, String? value, void onChange(val)) {
  return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
          child: SizedBox(
              //width: 80,
              height: 50,
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: const Text('Select unit'),
                value: value,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  onChange(val);
                },
                items: jsonList?.map((item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item['conversion'].toString(),
                        child: Text(item['name']),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                underline: Container(),
                isExpanded: true,
                
              ))));
              
}
```

here is the Json List

```
{
    "Length": [
        {
            "name": "Meter",
            "conversion": 1.0,
            "base_unit": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Millimeter",
            "conversion": 1000.0
        },
        {
            "name": "Centimeter",
            "conversion": 100.0
        }
    ]
}
```

as you guys can see that I am returning a **String** value from **['conversion']** and I am using **['name']** from jsonList to display the names. this works fine and I get the **['conversion']** values in return but what I want more is to store the **Selected** name in a variable as well. for example if I select **Meter** from dropdown button, it returns the **conversion** value on **onChanged** but I want to capture and assign the **selected name** as well to a variable.

So how can I do that and is it even possible?
appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class Unit {
  final String name;
  final double conversion;
  final bool baseUnit;
  const Unit(
      {required this.name, required this.conversion, this.baseUnit = false});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: MyDropdown(),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDropdown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyDropdown> createState() => MyDropdownState();
}

class MyDropdownState extends State<MyDropdown> {
  Unit? _selected;

  final _units = const <Unit>[
    Unit(name: 'Meter', conversion: 1.0, baseUnit: true),
    Unit(name: 'Millimeter', conversion: 1000.0),
    Unit(name: 'Centimeter', conversion: 100)
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<Unit>(
        value: _selected,
        onChanged: (selected) => setState(() {
              debugPrint(
                  'Selected name: ${selected?.name}}, conversion: ${selected?.conversion}');
              _selected = selected;
            }),
        items: _units
            .map((Unit unit) => DropdownMenuItem<Unit>(
                  value: unit,
                  child: Text(unit.name),
                ))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, it works flawlessly, but can I use Json data with it? because I already have tons of conversion data in Json file format. so I am wondering if its possible.

Comment: I would suggest to import your JSON data into instances of classes. You can create a `fromJson` method manually or use [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) to help you with code generation.

Comment: You can then read the JSON data from assets and populate the lists of objects you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any type for a `DropdownButton`, not only `String`. You can use your own model class types as well.

In your case since the value set is in a JSON, use `<Map<String, dynamic>>` as the type of both `DropdownButton` and `DropdownMenuItem`. This way the value will be a `Map` of the selected item so you can easily get both `name` and `conversion`.

This is a minimalistic example which you can try and adjust it to your needs:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: MyDropdown(),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDropdown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyDropdown> createState() => MyDropdownState();
}

class MyDropdownState extends State<MyDropdown> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? _selected;

  final _json = {
    'Length': [
      {'name': 'Meter', 'conversion': 1.0, 'base_unit': true},
      {'name': 'Millimeter', 'conversion': 1000.0},
      {'name': 'Centimeter', 'conversion': 100.0}
    ]
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        value: _selected,
        onChanged: (selected) => setState(() {
              debugPrint(
                  'Selected name: ${selected?['name']}, conversion: ${selected?['conversion']}');
              _selected = selected;
            }),
        items: _json['Length']
            ?.map((Map<String, dynamic> item) =>
                DropdownMenuItem<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Text(item['name']),
                ))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, This is exactly what i did before, to return the Map, but the problem I am encountering is that when I click on back button and go to another screen and when I come back to the same screen, I get the **items==null . There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: {name: Millimeter, conversion:
1000}. \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"**, this is the exact error, so my question is, does the **items** value support **MAP**

Comment: Maybe you should create a class and use that as a type. Instances of a class have a hashcode.

Comment: can you help me with that? I am very new to flutter and coding and I am stuck in this for days. I highly appreciate it.